# How to show all the posts in custom page

Tags: php, forms, hyperlink

I have page which contains some posts, if i click any post means it'll go to that specific post, For that I'm using this method.

Sample Post Code that I'm using.

```html
<a href="post.php?post=<?php echo $post_detail['id'] ?>">
  <div class="post-card">
     [post content]
  </div>
</a>
```

This is the method I'm currently using to view all post in my custom page "post.php".

Is there any other way to do the same beacause if I go with this method means Im getting bad URL view which i don't like.

URL I'm getting with this method.

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/post.php?post=post1
```

And I know there is a way to get rid of from this bad URL using htaccess but I'm eager to know is there is any other way to make this custom page view apart from this method.

Comment: normally you can use .htaccess to do what you want (as you have said) , Alternatively, amend the **php.ini**

Comment: how can i clean that url using htaccess,i tried using this but its not working. Htaccess code : RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?post=$1 [QSA,L]